# Image distortion after sending through a WSGI app in Python

Tags: python, wsgi

A lot of the time when I send image data over WSGI (using `wsgiref`), the image comes out distorted. As an example, examine the following:

[image: distorted Google logo]
<sub>(source: [evanfosmark.com](http://evanfosmark.com/files/goog.gif))</sub>

Comment: Looks like a "binary versus text" problem -- \n getting translated to \r\n or viceversa, or a control-Z getting in the way. I've never observed such issues myself, but then, I hardly use Windows these days (and on any other system it hardly matters if I'm sloppy with my 'r' vs 'rb' opens;-). Care to explain the platforms in question and show us the relevant code?

Comment: I'm doing this on Ubuntu linux.  And there really isn't code to show. All that's occuring is that I'm reading an image file and sending it to the WSGI server.

Comment: Sending it how? Alex is right. I've seen this exact problem happen when some piece of the stack converted a byte that looked like \n to \r\n in a .jpg

Comment: Please post code , whatever it is
"""All that's occuring is that I'm reading an image file and sending it to the WSGI server"""
sounds much is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you haven't posted the code, here is a simple code which correctly works
with python 2.5 on windows

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def serveImage(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    headers = [('Content-type', 'image/png')]
    start_response(status, headers)

    return open("about.png", "rb").read()

httpd = make_server('', 8000, serveImage)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

may be instead of "rb" you are using "r"

Answer (score 1):

It had to do with `\n` not being converted properly. I'd like to thank Alex Martelli for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the result is getting truncated? Try `wget` or `curl` to fetch the file directly and `cmp` it to the original image; that should help debug it. Beyond that, post your full code and environment details even if it's simple.