# python/cgi - serves distorted images

Tags: python, apache, http, header

I have been struggling for a couple hours now with serving jpg's with a python cgi site. For some reason the images always come out distorted.

Here is my code:

```
print('Content-type: image/jpg\n')
path = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\image.jpg'
print file(path, 'rb').read()
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967826/image-distortion-after-sending-through-a-wsgi-app-in-python) describes a nearly identical problem, however I am not using WSGI. I am using windows and apache and have played around with `\r\n\r\n` as well as `print 'Content-type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n',`. Similarly I have tried `print file(path, 'rb').read(),` thinking that a new line might be distorting the image somehow.

Any more troubleshooting ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

ps. The site must remain a cgi site.

[edit] changed to `print('Content-type: image/jpeg\n')`

[edit] example image: [image]

Comment: The MIME type for JPEGs is `image/jpeg` not `image/jpg`

Comment: thanks but that doesn't solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.codersger.de/mags/cscene/CS6/CS6-07.html) shows sending a file to CGI using C++. The program takes some care to convert stdout to binary:

```
int main()
{
#if _WIN32
    // Standard I/O is in text mode by default; since we intend
    // to send binary image data to standard output, we have to
    // set it to binary mode.
    // Error handling is tricky to say the least, so we have none.
    _fmode = _O_BINARY;
    if (_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _fmode) == -1) {}
    if (_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _fmode) == -1) {}
#endif
```

You could do this in python. [Here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65443-sending-binary-data-to-stdout-under-windows/) is a Windows-specific solution:

```
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import os, msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
```

[Here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html) is code specific to python 3.x:

> The standard streams are in text mode
>   by default. To write or read binary
>   data to these, use the underlying
>   binary buffer. For example, to write
>   bytes to stdout, use
>   sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'abc'). Using
>   io.TextIOBase.detach() streams can be
>   made binary by default. This function
>   sets stdin and stdout to binary:

```
def make_streams_binary():
    sys.stdin = sys.stdin.detach()
    sys.stdout = sys.stdout.detach()
```

---

Later: I also think that you should be able to UU64-encode your jpeg and send it over the wire as text with an appropriate content-length and content-type, but I've never done HTTP at this level. You'd have to look it up.